# Is there a way to define multiple type synonyms in a single line?

Tags: haskell

My code is currently like this:

```
type Speed = Float
type Height = Float
type FuelMass = Float
type Gravity = Float
```

is there a way to not be wasting so much space by grouping the declarations, like

```
type (Speed, Height, FuelMass, Gravity) = Float
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. A type definition is its own statement. If you really wanted to, you could group them on the same line by separating with semicolons instead of newlines, but this would be a very very unusual style.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can of course have any code generated for you by Template Haskell.

```
module MultiDefinitions where

import Language.Haskell.TH
import Control.Monad

multipleTypeSynonyms :: [Q Name] -> Q Type -> DecsQ
multipleTypeSynonyms synGs tG = do
  t <- tG
  forM synGs $ \synG -> do
    syn <- synG
    return $ TySynD syn [] t
```

Then

```
{-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}

import Language.Haskell.TH
import MultiDefinitions

multipleTypeSynonyms
    (newName <$> ["Speed", "Height", "FuelMass", "Gravity"]) [t| Float |]
```

will generate the same definitions you wrote manually.

Is it *a good idea* to du stuff like that with TH? Hardly. In fact it is also not clear that type synonyms like that are a good thing at all – many Haskellers would argue that you should either use `newtype`s that actually give additional type safety (or use existing library types, such as from [the `units` library](https://github.com/goldfirere/units/tree/master/units)), or else simply hard-code `Float`.

BTW there's seldom a good reason to use `Float`, just use `Double`.